# combine two result set side by side using mdx

Tags: mdx

**hi i am new to mdx,
i want to combine two select statement resultset (side by side like union) using mdx query,please any body help me to solve this query
first query:**

```
 SELECT
{ [Last Year] }
ON COLUMNS,

 { {[Location].[Location].&[7], [Location].[Location].&[12], [Location].[Location].&[11],
[Location].[Location].&[19], [Location].[Location].&[17], [Location].[Location].&[16],
[Location].[Location].&[9], [Location].[Location].&[18] },{[Location].[Location].[All]}}
ON ROWS

FROM [Cube1]

WHERE ( [Measures].[Labour %] )
```

**here [Last Year] is a calculated set**

[Last Year]=====

```
{STRTOMEMBER("[Date].[Month].&["+ cstr(year(now())-2) +"-11-01T00:00:00]"):
        (STRTOMEMBER("[Date].[Month].&["+ cstr(year(now())-1) +"-10-01T00:00:00]"))}
```

**2nd query:**

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Budget ] AS IIF(avg([Last Year],IIF(([Measures].[Budget]>0),[Measures].[Budget],null)),
                                        avg([Last Year],IIF(([Measures].[Budget]>0),[Measures].[Budget],null)),0.00),

MEMBER [Measures].[YTD] AS IIF(avg([Last Year], IIF(([Measures].[Labour %]>0),[Measures].[Labour %],null))<>null,
                              avg([Last Year], IIF(([Measures].[Labour %]>0),[Measures].[Labour %],null)),0.00),
FORMAT_STRING = "Standard",
BACK_COLOR = CASE WHEN [YTD] = 0  THEN /*White*/16777215 /*White*/  
WHEN [YTD] <= [Measures].[Budget ] THEN 65408
     WHEN [YTD]<= [Measures].[Budget ] +5 THEN 65535
     WHEN [YTD]> [Measures].[Budget ] +5 THEN 255
END,
VISIBLE = 1
SELECT
{  [Measures].[YTD], [Measures].[Budget ] }
ON COLUMNS,

{ { [Location].[Location].&[7], [Location].[Location].&[12], [Location].[Location].&[11], [Location].[Location].&[19], [Location].[Location].&[17], [Location].[Location].&[16], [Location].[Location].&[9], [Location].[Location].&[18] },{[Location].[Location].[All]} }
ON ROWS

FROM [Cube1]
```

**here   ==> [Measures].[YTD], [Measures].[Budget ] are calculated member
i want result like in

coulmns===> ytd,budget,nov,dec,jan,feb.,,,,,,,,,,october  and rows ====>  locations and total(average of all locations)

please guide me to get solution like mdx query**

Answer (score 0):

Your concept of "UNION" wont work for 2 main reasons:

**1.** You can't UNION members from different hierarchies. **2.** Query structures are different.

Only way to see them "side by side", would be to open the queries in two different windows.

Instead, if you just wanted to see a combined view of measures and members, use either of the queries below:

```
//Go for this if you want to see the Locations in output

WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Budget ] AS IIF(avg([Last Year],IIF(([Measures].[Budget]>0),[Measures].[Budget],null)),
                                        avg([Last Year],IIF(([Measures].[Budget]>0),[Measures].[Budget],null)),0.00),

MEMBER [Measures].[YTD] AS IIF(avg([Last Year], IIF(([Measures].[Labour %]>0),[Measures].[Labour %],null))<>null,
                              avg([Last Year], IIF(([Measures].[Labour %]>0),[Measures].[Labour %],null)),0.00),
FORMAT_STRING = "Standard",
BACK_COLOR = CASE WHEN [YTD] = 0  THEN /*White*/16777215 /*White*/  
WHEN [YTD] <= [Measures].[Budget ] THEN 65408
     WHEN [YTD]<= [Measures].[Budget ] +5 THEN 65535
     WHEN [YTD]> [Measures].[Budget ] +5 THEN 255
END,
VISIBLE = 1


SELECT
{  [Measures].[YTD], [Measures].[Budget ], [Measures].[Labour %] }
ON COLUMNS,
{ [Last Year] }
*
{ { [Location].[Location].&[7], 
[Location].[Location].&[12], 
[Location].[Location].&[11], 
[Location].[Location].&[19], 
[Location].[Location].&[17], 
[Location].[Location].&[16], 
[Location].[Location].&[9], 
[Location].[Location].&[18] },
{[Location].[Location].[All]} }
ON ROWS
FROM [Cube1]
```

OR

```
//A cleaner one. Go for this if you don't want to see the Locations in output

WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Budget ] AS IIF(avg([Last Year],IIF(([Measures].[Budget]>0),[Measures].[Budget],null)),
                                        avg([Last Year],IIF(([Measures].[Budget]>0),[Measures].[Budget],null)),0.00),

MEMBER [Measures].[YTD] AS IIF(avg([Last Year], IIF(([Measures].[Labour %]>0),[Measures].[Labour %],null))<>null,
                              avg([Last Year], IIF(([Measures].[Labour %]>0),[Measures].[Labour %],null)),0.00),
FORMAT_STRING = "Standard",
BACK_COLOR = CASE WHEN [YTD] = 0  THEN /*White*/16777215 /*White*/  
WHEN [YTD] <= [Measures].[Budget ] THEN 65408
     WHEN [YTD]<= [Measures].[Budget ] +5 THEN 65535
     WHEN [YTD]> [Measures].[Budget ] +5 THEN 255
END,
VISIBLE = 1


SELECT
{  [Measures].[YTD], [Measures].[Budget ], [Measures].[Labour %] }
ON COLUMNS,
{ [Last Year] } ON ROWS
FROM [Cube1]
WHERE
{ { [Location].[Location].&[7], 
[Location].[Location].&[12], 
[Location].[Location].&[11], 
[Location].[Location].&[19], 
[Location].[Location].&[17], 
[Location].[Location].&[16], 
[Location].[Location].&[9], 
[Location].[Location].&[18] },
{[Location].[Location].[All]} }
```